# Powershell archiving script

Tags: powershell

I found the below powershell script on "Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog"﻿ it is a great arching script. I modified it to meet my needs of a log file being created and sending an email. However i discovered that the move-file command is to slow and wanted to use robocopy instead. I used robocoopy but i keep receiving "ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Source Directory C:\shared\test\New Microsoft Visio Drawing.vsd\" I am not sure what can be causing this and was hoping that someone can help.

```
 [string] $server = 'Test'
 [string] $source = "c:\shared\test"
 [string] $target = "C:\shared\test1"
 [int] $days = 60
 $logdate = Get-Date -Format MM-dd-yy
 [string] $log = ('c:\shared\logs\testlog-'+ $logdate + '.log')

# Object created for shortcut creation

$wsh = new-object -comobject wscript.shell 



# Get all the files from the source path, that are not shortcuts and older than the days set

Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse |  

        Where-Object {!$_.psiscontainer -and ((get-date) - $_.lastwritetime).totaldays -gt $days -and $_.extension -ne ".lnk"} |

            ForEach-Object {

# For each file build the destination path 

                $dest = $_.fullname -replace ([regex]::escape($source)), $target



# Check if the destination file path has the parent directory, if not create it

                $parent = split-path $dest 

                if(!(test-path $parent)){

                    [void] (new-item -Path (split-path $parent) -Name (split-path $parent -leaf) -ItemType directory)

                } 



# Save the modification date and the ACL of the file for later use

                $date = $_.lastwritetime

                $acl = $_ | Get-Acl

# Try to move the file into the destination

                Robocopy.exe $_.fullname "$dest" /mov /e /zb /r:1 /copyall /nfl /np /LOG+:"$log"

                #Move-Item -Path $_.fullname -Destination $dest -Verbose -ErrorAction silentlycontinue *>&1 | Out-File -FilePath $log -Append



# If successful create shortcut

                if($?){

                    $shortCut = $wsh.CreateShortCut("$($_.fullname).lnk")    

                    $shortCut.TargetPath = $dest 

                    $shortCut.Save() 



# Set the "date modified" property of the shortcut same as date modified property of the original file

                    (Get-Item "$($_.fullname).lnk").lastwritetime = $date



# Replace the access control entries on the shortcut, so that users have read only access to it               

                    $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$true)

                    $acl | Set-Acl -Path "$($_.fullname).lnk"

                    $acl = Get-Item "$($_.fullname).lnk" | Get-Acl

                    $acl.Access | where-object {"BUILTIN\Administrators" -ne $_.identityreference -and "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -ne $_.identityreference} |

                        ForEach-Object {

                            $identity = $_.identityreference

                            [void] $acl.RemoveAccessRule($_)

                            $restrictedACE = New-Object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($identity,"ReadAndExecute",,,"Allow")

                            $acl.AddAccessRule($restrictedACE)

                        }

                    $acl | Set-Acl

                }

# Else write error message

                else { write-host "Error moving $_" -ForegroundColor red}

            }


#Mail Server Variables
$SMTPserver = "test.abc.com"
$from = "archivetest@abc.com"
$to = "test@abc.com"
$subject = $server + " Offline Data Archive Report " + $logdate


# Send email  
Send-MailMessage -From $from -To $to -SmtpServer $SMTPserver -Subject $subject -Body ('Attached is the log file for files Archived on ' + $server + ' on '  + $logdate ) -Attachments ( $log)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things i can suggest.

- Ensure that both the source and destination arguments are wrapped in double quotes, in this instance it appears `$_.fullname` is not.
- Check that the source and destination path don't exceed the Windows file path and name length specification (260 characters in total)
- Check that the source and destination paths don't contain any of the reserved file/path characters (< > ; " / \ | ? *)
- If that doesn't work attempt to capture the copy process with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) and post the capture file.